# Jitpack.io Not Get New Version of Dependency

Tags: android-studio, jitpack

I submit new version of android library in Github and get in on Jitpack but new version show in Jitpack but not get and in console return 404 error.
Error message is "message" : "Tag or commit not found: 0.5.6",
Same code i push to another repo and its working fine.
Can you please tell me whats issue.
[[Jitpack Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqgiq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94N1Y.png)